# could not able to install npm in ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: node.js, npm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9igJ.png)

> "Could not able to install following components in Ubuntu 16.04.2
>   version of Linux box getting error which is attached with screen shot "
>   Trying to install NPM components in LINUX box but it getting killed in the middle

```
{
  "name": "legaldialapis",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=DEV",
    "test": "mocha apis/**/test/**/*.spec.js",
    "test-watch": "nodemon --exec npm test",
    "code-cov": "nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=text-lcov npm test",
    "eslint": "eslint **/*.js > lint-report.txt",
    "bump": "gulp bump"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^4.9.2",
    "ajv-error-messages": "^1.0.0",
    "async": "^2.1.4",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "bunyan": "^1.8.5",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "dateformat": "^2.0.0",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "firebase": "^3.7.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^4.1.3",
    "json2yaml": "^1.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.22",
    "mongoose": "^4.8.1",
    "mongoose-gen": "^2.1.1",
    "request": "^2.79.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^1.8.2",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^1.0.2",
    "validator": "^6.2.1",
    "html-pdf": "2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-http": "^3.0.0",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "eslint": "^3.14.1",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.7.1",
    "gulp-bump": "^2.6.1",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "nyc": "^10.0.0",
    "yargs": "^6.6.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-mocha": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-folders": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
        "gulp-util": "^3.0.8"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.10.0"
       }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give more information? Error logs, commands used etc.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know! If you have a question, please read the help center on how to ask. Hint: Including the error message is a good start.

Comment: no error logs , was attached the screen shot

Comment: please you can check the error screen shot

[Scrren Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9igJ.png)

Comment: Now you removed the screenshot of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Wellm, the error message says it: **graceful-fs** in verison 3 and older is not compatible with **NodeJs** version 7 and above. So the two options you have are

- Search your dependencies for the one that depends on **graceful-fs** and see if you can update this (See error message: "Use `npm ls graceful-fs` to find it in the tree.")
- Check wheter the current LTS version of **NodeJs** `6.10.x` is supported by your dependencies

If you have not a complete overview, whether your dependencies are up to date, you can run [npm outdated](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated).

Hope this helps.

---

Probably a general remark to your question:

- It would be great to see the console output in your post; Not only as screen shot, but also as text I could copy/paste
- This looks like a prob with Node and/or npm. So the version for both 'd be very helpful

Comment: Running nodejs @ 6.4.0

Comment: So node version 6 won't work either. Which package depends on the deprecated **graceful-fs**? ("Use `npm ls graceful-fs` to find it in the tree.")

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution for this.
Have increased the space of Ubuntu droplet from 512 MB RAM and 10GB ROM to 2GB RAM and 20GB ROM.

This problem was due to space issue.

Thanks for your answers